# Circuit providing output?

Tags: terminology, power

What does it mean for a circuit to provide an output power of say 1000W? Is "circuit providing power" referring to the battery supplying energy to the external circuit, or is it referring to the power of the components? In general I'm just finding the terminology used in electricity a bit confusing.

EDIT:

[image]

What does "circuit provide an output power" mean?

Comment: In this case, they are referring to how much heat dissipation the elements will have. In series the voltage will be split across the 2 elements and each will have less voltage across it and hence less power dissipated. In parallel the same voltage will be across both, so they will both have the 500W of dissipation, adding to a total of 1kW.

Comment: @I.Wolfe: Thanks, I thought it was heat dissipation but calling it an "output" was a bit confusing for me. Is it common to call it an output power even if it's referring to heat dissipation? Thanks

Comment: Usually it would say "one of the circuits dissipates 1kW". It is worded kind of misleading, probably an oversight.

Comment: Well I just looked up Watts vs Joules, since I would expect to hear watts dissipated vs joules of heat. Watts is Joules per second, so technically the parallel combination will supply 1kJ of heat, which over a second would be 1kW. I still think the proper wording would be watts dissipated, but I guess technically the question isn't "wrong".

Comment: @I.Wolfe You've got it backwards. In parallel, the heaters provide a constant 1 kW of power regardless of the amount of time (ignoring instantaneous vs. RMS subtleties). The heat is proportional to time: over 1 s, they will generate 1 kJ.

Comment: In this case they mean "the heaters will output 1000W of heat"

Comment: @jerry Yup, you are correct. A Watt is a J/s so it is the rate. Had the equation right but mixed the explanation up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When someone says a circuit provides an output power they are referring to the amount of power that is delievered to the load and can be used to do work or processing.  When someone says a circuit *dissipates* a given amount of power they typically mean that amount of power is converted to waste heat in the course of processing and cannot be used by other circuits.

Comment: consumes and dissipates are not the same thing, but otherwise good answer. Components dissipate some power as heat, but a circuit consumes power for all sorts of reason, such as running motors, turning servos, lighting LEDs, etc.

Comment: I agree with you, but most people use them as synonyms in practice, right or wrong.  I was trying to relate to the asker that if he or she hears those words that's probably what they mean.

Comment: But that's not what they mean. I agree with your description of *dissipates*, but *consumes* is really the total input. For example, a ideal linear regulator with 5V at 1A output from 12V input *consumes* 12W, *dissipates* 7W, and *delivers* or *provides* 5W.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Hello, I didn't want to post the question I was originally doing (because of the homework policy on stackexchange) but I think it's necessary here so I have attached it. (Technically this isn't homework, I'm just revising for an upcoming exam by doing past papers.) -- See original post, I have edited in the question.)

Comment: @I.Wolfe: Hello, I didn't want to post the question I was originally doing (because of the homework policy on stackexchange) but I think it's necessary here so I have attached it. (Technically this isn't homework, I'm just revising for an upcoming exam by doing past papers.) -- See original post, I have edited in the question.)

Comment: @OlinLathrop  Fair enough.  I've updated my answer.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: If an ideal linear regulator is connected to a 12 volt source and can push 1 ampere through a 5 ohm load, then the load will consume/dissipate 5 watts, the regulator will consume/dissipate 7 watts, and the entire circuit - not just the regulator - will consume/dissipate the 12 watts you incorrectly state the regulator will.

Answer (score 2):

Heating elements can be thought of as large resistors that consume power to give off heat. Each one in this problem dissipates 500W of power at 230V.

The purpose of this question is to see if you understand parallel versus series connections of resistances.

When resistances are in series, they add. When the resistance increases, the current through the circuit decreases. In the series combination, the higher resistance will lead to lower current consumption, which means less power consumption (voltage supplied is still 230V and power = voltage * current).

When voltage is applied to resistances in parallel, each resistance sees the same voltage across it, in this case 230V. With each element seeing the rated 230V, they will both consume 500W and provide 1kW of heat total.

The question should ask why only one of the circuits dissipates 1kW, it is probably an oversight. I see stuff like this a lot on tests or in books. The question is still understandable as is, so they usually don't fix things like this.

Technically a Joule is a Watt*second or unit of heat, and a Watt is Joules per second or the rate of heat dissipation. So it does sound odd to say it supplies X Watts of heat, but it's not incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds wrong because for most devices, dissipating power as heat is undesirable.

For an op-amp, a speaker, or an LED, the "output" is a voltage, a sound, or light.  These devices will all also generate some heat which is usually undesired and considered as "used up" or "dissipated."

Only in the case of a *heating element* is the "output" the rate of heat production.  So the question isn't worded incorrectly; it's referring to a 1kW rate of heating rather than 1kW of power being dissipated/consumed.  The two values just happen to be equal.